# convert variadic iterator arguments to tuple of value types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

How can I convert a template parameter pack of `IteratorTypes` to a tuple of the respective `value_type`s?
I tried the following, but it failed with

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 1)
using ValueTypes = typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorTypes...>::value_type;
                                                                              ^
```

---

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

template <typename ... IteratorTypes>
void foo(IteratorTypes&&...its)
{
    using ValueTypes = typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorTypes...>::value_type;
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::tuple<ValueTypes>,std::tuple<int,float>>::value, "types do no match");
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> int_vec(1);
    std::vector<float> float_vec(1);

    foo(int_vec.begin(), float_vec.begin());
    return 0;
}
```

[Live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cde93d2f978d1572)

Comment: The corresponding *pack* would be `typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorTypes>::value_type...`, but that's still a pack and not a type; e.g. you need to stick it into a tuple.

Comment: @KerrekSB if only one could typedef a pack ...

Comment: I don't know. There'd be no end to new obscurities and bugs and crazy code. The idea is a lot less innocent than it may sound.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `...` goes immediately after the *pattern* you want to expand.

```
using ValueTypes = std::tuple<typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorTypes>::value_type...>;
static_assert(std::is_same<ValueTypes, std::tuple<int,float>>::value, "types do no match");
```

Also, you should probably `std::decay` `IteratorTypes` before passing it to `iterator_traits`, or take them by value rather than by forwarding reference.

Answer (score 0):

...or to make it easier to read:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename ... IteratorTypes>
void foo(IteratorTypes&&...its)
{
    using value_type_tuple = std::tuple<typename IteratorTypes::value_type...>;
    using desired_tuple = std::tuple<int, float>;
    static_assert(std::is_same<value_type_tuple , desired_tuple>::value, "types do no match");
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> int_vec(1);
    std::vector<float> float_vec(1);

    foo(int_vec.begin(), float_vec.begin());
    return 0;
}
```